# Scheme Error Object Is Not Applicable

Tags: scheme

I am writing a Scheme function that detects if a word is in a list of words. My code uses an if statement and memq to return either #t or #f. However, something is causing the first parameter to return the error that the object is not applicable.

```
(define in?                                                                     
  (lambda (y xs)                                                                
    ((if (memq( y xs )) #t #f))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses matter:

```
(define in?                                                                     
  (lambda (y xs)                                                                
    (if (memq y xs) #t #f)))
```

so

- you have double parentheses before `if`
- you put `memq` parameters between parentheses

BTW, you can also express this as

```
(define in?                                                                     
  (lambda (y xs)                                                                
    (and (memq y xs) #t)))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm new to Scheme and much more accustomed to C++ and Java where you can have a billion unneeded ()'s and not suffer for it.

Comment: You are welcome. I was looking for a duplicate but actually didn't find any with this precise error message (which Scheme implementation are you using?). If you search for "application: not a procedure" which is the error you'd get in Racket, you'll find similar questions here on SO.