# The object ____ is not applicable

Tags: scheme, lisp

I keep receiving "The object 5.32 is not applicable" after running (main 1 2) then inputting 2 and finally -1. 5.32 is the correct answer. It just throws the mentioned error. (Should return ;Value 5.32).

I think my issue may be in my tax function, but am unsure. Any suggestions?

```
(define (add total num)(+ total num))
(define (tax total) (* total 1.065))

(define (main total x) 
  (if (= x -1) 
     (tax total)
  ((let ((z (add total x)))(let ((y (read)))(main z y))))
  )
)
```

And yes, I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976298/the-object-is-not-applicable)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287081/scheme-error-object-is-not-applicable), though neither location answers the question in a general format.

Comment: This is not Common Lisp, it looks like Scheme. But you have some other parentheses problems.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses around the first `let`.

Comment: @Barmer thank you. Do you mind explaining why the extra parentheses caused the error? I'm new to Lisp and Scheme (thanks for mentioning that by the way), and genuinely want to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses around the third expression in `if`. The syntax is:

```
(if <condition>
    <true-expression>
    <false-expression>)
```

but you wrote:

```
(if <condition>
    <true-expression>
    (<false-expression>))
```

Putting the expression in parentheses turns it into a procedure call, where it tries to use the value returned by `let` as a procedure.

There's also no need to use multiple `let`s, you can bind more than one variable at a time.

```
(define (main total x) 
  (if (= x -1) 
      (tax total)
      (let ((z (add total x))
            (y (read)))
          (main z y)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! It's very helpful.